# Using regex to duplicate end of line character

Tags: regex, list, character, notepad++

I am editing a list and i want to use regex in notepad++ to duplicate a character in a list.

For example i have

```
John
Dave
Mark
```

I want to manipulate it to say

```
Johnn
Davee
Markk
```

Is this possible in Notepad++ using regex commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Find:**

```
(.)$
```

This will capture a character before the end of a line.

`(...)` = create capturing group

`.` = any character

`$` = end of line

**Replace:**

```
\1\1
```

Replace with the captured character twice.

`\1` = first capturing group